# microcontroller fails at malloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, microcontroller

I am writing a function on a 32-bit cortex m4 microcontroller.
The function has to be able to multiply matrices of different sizes, which I cannot predict. So i Have to use a malloc...

But I don't understand why my mc always goes into default handler interrupt when it executes following line:

```
double *output2=NULL;
output2 = malloc(3 *1* sizeof(double *));
```

Is this mc not able to handle this type of operations?
While this works perfectly fine on my laptop!

**EDIT*

Here by some more code (which still needs to be modified...):
Well all malocs anywhere fail. I cannot assign any value to a "malloced" array.

```
int main (void)
{

    /*some stuff*/

    float transFRotMatrix[3][3]={0}; //array gets modified by other functions
    float sunMeasurements[3][1] = {{1},{2},{3}}; //test values

        multiplyMatrices( &transFRotMatrix[0][0],3, 3, &sunMeasurements[0][0], 3, 1, *orbitalSunVector);

    /*some stuff*/
}

void multiplyMatrices(float *transposedMatrix, int height1, int width1, float *iSunVector,int height2, int width2, float *orbitalSunVector)
{

    int y=0;
    int x = 0;
    int row=0;
    int column =0;
    int k=0;
    int k2 = 0;
    float result = 0;

    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int t=0;

    float rotationMatrix[3][3]={0};

    i=0;
    k=0;
    k2 = 0;


    if(width1 != height2)
    {
        printf("unmatching matrices, error.\n\n");
        return;
    }

    float *output2;

    output2 = malloc(3 *1* sizeof(float *)); //<-----ERROR


    while(k<width1) //aantal rijen 1ste matrix
    {
        for(j=0;j<height2;j++) //aantal rijen 2de matrix
        {
            result += (*((transposedMatrix+k*width1)+j)) * (*((iSunVector+j*width2)+k2));  //1ste var:aantal kolommen 2de matrix  --2de variabele na de plus = aantal kolommen 2de matrix
            //printf("%f * %f\t + ", (*((transposedMatrix+k*width1)+j)), (*((iSunVector+j*width2)+k2)));
        }

        output2[k*3 +k2] = result;  //<-----FAILS HERE


        k2++;
        x++;
        column++;

        if(x==width2)
        {
            k2=0;
            x=0;
            column=0;
            row++;
            y++;
            k++;

        }
        result = 0;

    }

    for(i=0;i<height1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<width2;j++)
        {
             orbitalSunVector[j * height1 + i] = output2[i*3 +j];
        }
    }
    free(output2);
}
```

Comment: maybe he doesnt support floating point?

Comment: Best to isolate the floating point issue like @Zelldon suggests. What happens if you malloc(20) into an int* ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is the malloc call which fails, and not some code after it? Afaik you should be allocating `3 * sizeof( double )` (at least if I understand it correctly - your code is very hard to read due to the way you use spaces) - that is likely twice the amount of bytes as  `3 * sizeof( double* )` so you might be accessing out of bounds data somewhere

Comment: @trilolil If you want array of doubles, then `sizeof(double*)` is definitely wrong. Perhaps you need to post more code.

Comment: As pointed out by others, `output2 = malloc(3 *1* sizeof(double *));` is wrong, it should be `output2 = malloc(3 * 1 * sizeof *output2);` to allocate 3x1 `double`s. By dereferencing the `output2` pointer we don't need to repeat the type name, and will get an error if `output2` is renamed or removed. This fix doesn't address the fault you're seeing, though.

Comment: Best practices recommend to check the [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) return value. You don't do that. If indeed it fails, then at least you could handle it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `malloc()` working fine in other part of this code ? As you are programming an embedded device, the heap may not have been properly initialized, or it have been initialized for another custom `malloc()`-like function.

Comment: This is actually the only malloc I use. I didn't do anything for the heap. Hereby a screenshot: http://imgur.com/JT5W5tK

Comment: Well all malocs anywhere fail. I cannot assign any value to a "malloced" array.

Comment: You need to check your compiler/linker doc to correctly initialize your libc and/or you heap. If you have enough RAM and no threads, a much more simple solution is to allocate a global variable for the biggest possible allocation and use it.

Comment: You were right! thank you very much. There was no heap allocated at all. 0

Answer (score 0):

There are two valid types of implementations in C: *hosted* and *freestanding*. Programs written for hosted implementations may use any of the standard library headers. However, freestanding implementations are only required to support `<float.h>`, `<iso646.h>`, `<limits.h>`, `<stdalign.h>`, `<stdarg.h>`, `<stdbool.h>`, `<stddef.h>`, `<stdint.h>`, and `<stdnoreturn.h>`.

It's not uncommon for microcontrollers to have minimal support, so perhaps your C compiler (or rather, standard library) doesn't have full support for `<stdlib.h>` (and hence `malloc`). However, without knowing which compiler and standard library you've chosen to use, that's just a guess.

It's also possible that, as the comments for your question suggest, something prior to (and/or following) this piece of code is to blame. Perhaps you could produce an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Please feel free to comment underneath this answer when you've updated to give more information, and I'll happily elaborate to provide more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am coding using code composer studio from texas instrument  5.4.0.00091. I edited my question to provide some more code. (altough there is strictly nothing more previously to those lines)

Answer (score 0):

What you received was an processor exception, not an interrupt.
They're all mapped to the same handler which is a common practice.
I assume that you got Hardware fault.
You can check the registers to see what caused the exception.
Use [this code](http://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) as a reference to examine them.
It could be related to the libc implementation if the exception occurs inside malloc.